water leaks around bathroom ceiling AC register
We have a small water closet with a toilet in our master bath. There is an exhaust fan and AC register on the ceiling close to each other.
Every year in the summer when the AC is running a lot we get water dripping though the ceiling around the AC register.  We do not use the fan at all unless we are cleaning the room to get rid of fumes.
We have been told the problem is the warm air gets through the exhaust fan (or around it) and causes condensation around the cool AC vent. We have been told that insulation around the fan and sealing any gaps around it will solve the problem.  Does that seem reasonable? We have had the vents in the attic insulated thinking that was the problem and it did not help.  We have taped over the cover to the fan to try to prevent air from getting up there and it did nothing. It only happens in the summer when AC is on so it is not a roof leak.
Any advice would be appreciated
Thanks,
Eric

Humid air from any source and cooler surfaces will cause condensation.  Same as a cold glass of liquid, a toilet tank when humid in the house.  Insulating the AC duct should help.

Also, if you can (re)arrange the register so that it blows away from the exhaust, that would help.  You can use a vent deflector if the louvers in the register provide insufficient redirection of the airflow.

I had a small bath that had the same problem, and yes any extra insulating did nothing.
I installed a programable timer switch for the exhaust fan.  One that I could program to come on for 5 minutes every 2 hours. It took me some experimentation to find the amount of duration and schedule to work. However the idea was to get the humid air out of the room so there was not so much humidity to condense on the AC duct.
The fan itself was a bit noisy so I changed that to a nice quiet model. ( Wife wanted a new one anyway.)  It ran and corrected the issue and we never new it was running unless we were next to the room or in it.

What fan did you get?  I assume ours has a leaky damper and needs to be replaced

I don't remember the exact model. It was a Nutone/ broan.  That was 3 years ago or so.
